# vb.net insert data from listcheckbox to datagridview when an item checked and deleted when unchecked item

Tags: vb.net

When I check a car make the *car_model* appear from database and when I check the *car_model* it's added automatically to *datagridview1*.

My question is when I try to check another *car_make* to add the new *car_model* of this car make to the DataGridView all the DataGridView items are deleted due to the (DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()) that I put in the code.

However, when I remove this comand the code duplicates every thing, can you help me solving this problem.

```
Private Sub acar_modelbox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles car_modelbox.SelectedIndexChanged
    
    Dim itemChecked1 As Object
    For Each itemChecked1 In car_makelistbox.CheckedItems
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Next
    Dim itemChecked2 As Object
    For Each itemChecked2 In car_modelbox.CheckedItems

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(combobox1.SelectedItem("Id").ToString, (combobox1.SelectedItem("carvin").ToString, itemChecked1.item("car_make").ToString, itemChecked2.item("car_model").ToString)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can make use of the [CheckedListBox.ItemCheck Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event to know when a single item is checked or unchecked and then accordingly. I can't suggest a proper coded answer for a solution as you haven't given enough code showing how all your controls are populated.

Comment: Why would you call .Clear several times in a For loop?

Comment: You declare both `itemChecked1` and `itemChecked2` as `Object`. Then you try to used `.item` on the `Object` but `Object` has no such property or method.

Comment: You are looping through all the checked items every time the event code runs. You only want to add the item that was clicked, not a loop.

Comment: @JayV Hello bro , i try to make checklistbox.event but the problem is when i check the model of the car it's add for me all the row on datagridview it's ok, but when i try to check another make to add the new models to the datagridview ,then all the data cleared because i put datagridview.row.clear(), i want to add data to datagridview even if i check a new make of car and new model it must add the new data to the old data on the datagridview , thank you.